# crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ed25519') does not verify simple test, which an 'ec' keypair verifies without issue. What is the mistake?

Tags: node.js, ed25519

Been playing around with the crypto module in Nodejs and using crypto.generateKeyPairSync. When running a short verification test with 'ec' keys, this evaluates as expected, but when testing with 'ed25519' generated keys, this never evaluates to true.

```
  const crypto = require('crypto')

  let identity = {}

  identity.identifierKeys__ = await crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
    namedCurve: 'secp256k1', // Options
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem'
    }
  })
  identity.identifierKeys = await crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ed25519', {
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem'
    }
  })
// console.log(identity.identifierKeys)
// test keys
  let key = identity.identifierKeys__ // if i swap to .identifierKeys, never evaluates to true
  let msg = 'testingInformation'
  let v = await crypto.createSign('SHA256')
      v.write(msg)
      v.end()
  let sig = await v.sign(key.privateKey, 'base64')
  let t = await crypto.createVerify('SHA256')
      t.write(msg)
      t.end()
  let r = await t.verify(key.publicKey, sig, 'base64')

  console.log(sig)
  console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NodeJS provides two implementations for signing/verifying, the [`Sign`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-sign)/[`Verify`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-verify) class (since v0.1.92) and [`crypto.sign()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptosignalgorithm-data-key-callback)/[`crypto.verify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptoverifyalgorithm-data-key-signature-callback) (since v12.0.0).

Signing and verifying with Ed25519 (and Ed448) is possible with `crypto.sign()` and `crypto.verify()`:

```js
...
let msg = 'testingInformation'
var signature = crypto.sign(null, Buffer.from(msg), identity.identifierKeys.privateKey)
var verified = crypto.verify(null, Buffer.from(msg), identity.identifierKeys.publicKey, signature)
console.log(signature.toString('base64'))
console.log(verified)
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting that Sign/Verify does not work, but crypto.sign & crypto.verify works like a charm, thanks very much.